# Reading text file in C

Tags: c, file-io, fopen, textinput, getch

My professor gave us the code to get input from a text file. The issue is it will not compile properly for me. I'm not sure where he (or I) went wrong. I have not modified his code in any way and my txt file is in the same directory as the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
     FILE *fp;
     char ch;
     fp = fopen("IronHeelShort.txt", "r");
     printf("Data inside file : ");
     while(1)
     {
         ch = fgetc(fp);
         printf("%c", ch);
         if (ch == EOF)
         break;

     }
     getch();
}
```

Comment: So what is the error message

Comment: You should check that the file opened. `ch` should be an `int`. You should check if `ch` is `EOF` *before* printing `ch`. Your prof is an idiot. What compiler/OS are you using?

Comment: _"Won't compile"_ does not mean anything. What is the error message your compiler display? Surely it must blame you for `getch()`? This should give you a hint: http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/conio.h/getch

Comment: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getch'.
undefined reference to getch.
ld returned 1 exit status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ch`should be an `int` anyway
The function `fgetc()` will always return an `int`, to handle all the char values and `EOF` which is negative.
Here reading your file will prematurely end when finding character `0xFF`.

For the compiling issue, change `getch()` into `getchar()`

Comment: Thanks :) I have done the edits. However can you tell me why is EOF not defined to be -1. From my stdio.h file : `#define EOF (-1)`

Comment: After changing ch to int and changing getch() to getchar(). I get segmentation fault(core dumped) after running?

Comment: @ValentinMercier "From my stdio.h file" is not the same as "defined in the standard". I was whining exactly about this kind of sloppiness found in a C++ textbook at my university (they asserted that `wchar_t` is defined as `unsigned short`, which it may or may not be.) - anyway,  +1.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't know what POSIX or similar standards require (maybe POSIX states that `EOF` is -1). But the C standard doesn't say anything about `EOF` besides that it should be distinct to every valid character cast to an `unsigned char` and that it should be negative. I don't know if there is any system defining it to something else than -1.

Comment: Thanks for these enlightening comments :) By the way for the record I have -1 on Mac OS X

Comment: @user1798299 the segfault can only be due to a failure to open your file. Please verify that it exists and is next to your program.

Comment: @user3477950: On my (all?) Linux machine, `wchar_t` is 4 bytes and holds Unicode code points encoded as UTF-32… So, that's not just sloppiness, it's just sticking to a certain platform (maybe that MS platform being somehow unable to distinguish between UCS-2 and UTF-16?).

Comment: @mafso I said "sloppiness" exactly because it's sticking to a certain platform, which results in students being exposed to only part of the truth. That's what I call "sloppy", but maybe it's not the right expression to use (I'm not a native English speaker).

Answer (score 1):

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char ch;
    fp = fopen("C:/emule/c/0.html", "r");
    printf("Data inside file : ");
    while (1)
    {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        printf("%c", ch);
        if (ch == EOF)
            break;

    }
    _getch();
}
```

UPD

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
    FILE *input = NULL;
    char c;

    input = fopen("D:/c/text.txt", "rt");
    if (input == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file");
        scanf("1");
        exit(0);
    }
    while (fscanf(input, "%c", &c) == 1) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%c", c);
    }

    fclose(input);
    scanf("1");
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you tell him what is wrong with his code. The man might learn something.

Comment: as You use getch I suppose it is VSE. fopen and getch won't work now as unsafe. use _getch and _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS to compile. Beside that, it is bad idea to check for EOF, as it is not defined in standard. Better to check how many chars were properly read from file.

Comment: It would be better to wait for a second, I'm not a code monkey.

Comment: I get a fatal error when adding in #include <conio.h>. Error is: No such file or directory. Compilation terminated. Using Ubuntu.

Comment: so you don't use Windows)

Comment: Monkey or Homo sapiens, it would be better to take time and prepare a complete answer before spitting _something_ for the votez.

Comment: well despite of OS see UPD